# redirect after few second on click jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have a small issue, i want to redirect page on click using jquery
here is my code

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
   window.location.href='index.php';
})
```

Now is there any way to delay redirect for 5 second.. i mean when click on button user wait  at least 5 second on same page and then redirect to index.php  i also tried this but it's not working

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
       window.location.href='index.php';
    } 5000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#submit').click(function()
{
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href='index.php'; }, 5000);       
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's working

Comment: excellent, glad to hear ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` function.

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.href='index.php';
  },5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var delay = 1000; //Your delay in milliseconds
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location = URL; }, delay);
});
```